# Find out ABAP program last execution date and time?

Tags: abap

I want to read the last run date of ABAP executable program then
purchase requisitions are retrieved from the date of the last run. I have tried different forums but could find a suitable solution for my requirement?

Standard table Name **FRUN** does not have an entry as well.

Comment: The forums say that the "last run date" is not stored, and that if the last run is recent you may get the information in the statistics, and that eventually you may activate Usage & Procedure Logging. Some programs store the run date themselves in some particular tables, that would help to know which program you are talking about...

Comment: statistics can not help because I have to use Current Date and Time Logic in ABAP Program. further can you please let me know what are the particular tables where i can find value of run date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use audit for that:

1. Activate audit using `SM19` tcode
2. Check audit log via `SM20` tcode

Another option is to use `STAD` transaction which collect statistics